# Meaning of DTC Code 4331 for Volvo EPS (Electrical Power Steering Module)

Tags: volvo, dtc, s40, eps, v50

It's possible I am reading the scan tool wrong or it is investigating a module that does not exist. For a **2008 Volvo S40** I get the following:

```
EPS - Electrical Power Steering Module

4331(1/1) Not Active

The definition for this trouble code is not available. …
```

I've looked everywhere online for this code. I cannot find what it means. I called the scan tool manufacturer and they told me it is a proprietary Volvo code. However, I have doubts about their answer.

I've looked up EPS failures online and came upon some information about Ford installing failure-prone modules in the racks on some vehicles. (Volvo was manufactured by Ford around that time.) On the other hand, I know the Volvo has a reservoir and pump hidden under the right fender. Perhaps this code means the EPS is not installed or the reader just cannot communicate with it.

Does anyone know what the *Volvo DTC of 4331 for the EPS* mean?

Comment: What tool are you using and what is the year/model is your car?

Comment: 2008 Volvo V50 (should be same as 2008 Volvo S40). Tool is [Innova 5160](http://pro.innova.com/Product/FullDetail/5160)